# does SKSpriteNode recognize gesture?

Tags: ios, swift, image, gesture, skspritenode

i build a wall and the bricks are not moving but i need to have one of them calling some info. this code below is inside a function may be should have this brick global

```
    let brk = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: imgName)
    if (imgName == "brickinfo"){
        brk.name = "brickinfo"
    }


    brk.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMinX(self.frame)+brkx, y: CGRectGetMinY(self.frame)+brky)
    if (imgName == "brickinfo"){
        let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("ShowInfo"))
        singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        brk.userInteractionEnabled = true

        //brk.addGestureRecognizer(ShowInfo) //do not exist
    }

    brk.xScale = 0.2
    brk.yScale = 0.2

    addChild(brk)
```

i am using the same code for other moving images which mean they have SKAction so when i click on them, touches began is fired. they both using the same code, add a name, addchild().

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
   /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        //675
        //30
        print(self.nodeAtPoint(location).name)
        if let theName = self.nodeAtPoint(location).name {
```

but the name of "brickinfo" is always coming back nil.
Can this brick image fired touchesbegan?
Thank you

Comment: what is the difference between:  let touch = touches.first!
    if myNode.containsPoint(touch.locationInNode(self)) {
        print("touched")
    } and for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

Comment: ok i will ask another question i don't need a specific gesture, just a touch and this for touch in touches does not work for some reason on static images but work perfectly on the images moving, make no sense right now. If it has a name, as it does do something.

Answer (score 0):

ok i was not looking for gesture, i thought i needed to add gesture to trigger the image, but i only needed to have this image responding with its name. After 3-4 days looking at many different ways to do it, i found the solution and it is pretty easy, the **zposition** was not set up for this specific brick. Now of course this bring its own problem. Sorry for the title of the question. Does xcode comes with a zposition layer view in 3D?
Thank you